# Text link and baseline problems

Tags: html, css

I'm having trouble aligning a simple text link to a website that I'm building. It's wrapped inside a paragraph which is inside a content div. I've tried setting the display to inline but the problem is the text link drops from its baseline. I've also attempted to write a CSS rule targeting the anchor by removing the white space (white-space: nowrap;) but nothing seems to work. I've obviously created an error some where along the line. Could any of you kind folk help me out please?

```css
#content {
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-left: 110px;
  margin-right: 110px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  text-align: left;
  font-family: 'Times New Roman';
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 22px;
  color: #457b9d;
}
#content p {
  color: #000000;
  padding: 0px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  margin-left: 1px;
  margin-right: 1px;
}
#content a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #73b9e6;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: inline;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
  <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. Learn more <a href="#">about Joe</a></p>
</div>
```

For privacy reasons I've taken out the original text and I'm using a bespoke font which I've changed for the sake of demonstration purposes to Times.

Hope I've included all the relevant parts. I'm a newbie so go easy! Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure I see what the problem is. A link is kind of like a span, it doesn't affect layout unless you've added CSS that does so. At least, in the demo provided, I don't see any issue at all with the link.

Comment: Not seeing the issue...https://jsfiddle.net/rw0L3md5/2/

Comment: Aligning to what exactly ? seems fine if you want it aligned with the rest of the `p`

Comment: Perhaps I ought to provide a screen-grab? It's definitely not lining up with the text in my original html doc. There is CSS applied to the anchor as you can see from the code I provided. In both Chrome and IE the link element drops slightly from the baseline of the paragraph.

Comment: Did you try setting the same `vertical-align` to both the `p` and the `a`? e.g. `vertical-align:bottom`, are you sure they both use the same font/font-size/font-weight?